# Changing the references after changing the directory

Tags: html, css

I have all the files related to my website in public_html folder and everything is working well.

For some reason, I have to keep the index.html file only in the public_html and move all the other files in a new folder public_html/xyz

I did that but the references to the files/folders in index.html are yet assuming the files to be in public_html.

How do I change the references ? Manually, its gonna take a long time..

Does someone has a quick trick?

Comment: if you were using webstorm it would be automatic...but otherwise, just do a Find + Replace and search for `src="` and `href="` and replace it with `src="xyz/` etc.

Comment: Move your current index.html into the new folder. Create a new index.html and have a link/redirect to the public/xyz/index.html file